# Custom Web Browser is too Slow

Tags: android, android-browser

I am using a custom web browser to load story from the url, which i am getting through intent. But the custom web view takes a lot time loading the web page. But if i load the same url in android browser or in System's Browser that loads quite fast. Is there any way of optimization there in Custom Web View, so that it loads web page quickly or it is dependent upon android OS..???? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why android webview is much slower than the native android browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991639/why-android-webview-is-much-slower-than-the-native-android-browser)

Answer (score 0):

refer the following link, this will help you

http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html